# Text Messages with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sms

I used pure HTML to compose a text message SMS by simply adding a special href value where normally regular URLs go like below:

```
<a href="sms:+33xxxxxxxx?body=Hello!">
    Compose SMS!
</a>
```

I created a text field to enter the phone number.

```
<input type="text" id="numPhone" style="width: 203px;">
```

I want the SMS HTML code use the value of this field so I tried like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var phone = $('#numPhone').val();
</script>

<a href="sms:${phone}?body=Hello!">
    Compose SMS!
</a>
```

But when I click to compose SMS, I get a empty recipient.
Please any help to use the field value in SMS code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do things like "`${phone}`" in [JS template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). That syntax is not part of HTML. Additionally, it would have to use an [event listener](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to update the link whenever the user updates the input field, and not just when the page initially loads. You would have to do something like this.

```
<a id="composeSMS">
    Compose SMS!
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#numPhone').on('input', function() {
        $('#composeSMS').attr('href', 'sms:' + this.value + '?body=Hello!');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. There is no action when I click the link!

Comment: There, I edited my answer so the code runs whenever the input field is updated.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but didn't work. Here the code: https://jsfiddle.net/Hnacer/j1x9w8Lu/6/

Comment: Oops, I forgot not to use a jQuery object for the `input` element in the event listener. I edited it again and it should work now; I just tested it.

Comment: Sorry but the code is not edited. If possible can you put it in jsfiddle ? Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j1x9w8Lu/7/
Here, I literally just copied the code from my current answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-` attribute to set the known part of the `href`. Then set the value of `href` in JavaScript with the value of `data-` and dynamic part:

```js
function updateLink(input){
  var phone = $(input).val();
  $('#compose').attr('href', $('#compose').attr('data-href1') + phone + $('#compose').attr('data-href2'));
}
updateLink('#numPhone');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="compose" href="" data-href1="sms:" data-href2="?body=Hello!">
    Compose SMS!
</a>
<input type="text" id="numPhone" style="width: 203px;" value="+33xxxxxxxx" oninput="updateLink('#numPhone')">
```